# I want to pass data to the card component in Angular but I got this 404 error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, components

I want to show the student info in a separate card component but I can't pass the data correctly to this card and I got an error said "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()".

### student.component.html

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/card', student.getId()]">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-100" (click)="toggleCard(student)">Info</button>
          </a>
```

### student.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css'],
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  students: Student[] = [];
  student: Student | undefined;
  public showCard: boolean = false;


  constructor(private studentService: StudentService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllStudents();

    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || '';
    this.studentService.getStudentById(id).subscribe(student => this.student = student);
  }


  public toggleCard(student: Student): void {
    this.showCard = !this.showCard;
  }
```

### card.component.html

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
          <img src="{{ student?.getImageUrl() }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ student?.getFirstName() }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ student?.getEmail() }}</p>
            <a href="{{ student?.getCin() }}" class="btn btn-primary">View Profile</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### card.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from 'src/app/models/Student';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() student: Student | undefined;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

### app.routing

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './components/student/student.component';
import { CardComponent } from './components/card/card.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'student', component: StudentComponent },
  { path: 'card', component: CardComponent },
  { path: 'card/:id', component: CardComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

### this is the result of the student component (it works but I got this console error):

[image]

### card component (/undefined) !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the your `studend-card` is loaded before loading the route because the `id` is null and it's replaced by `''` in your http call. That's why you have a 404.

You can try:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
filter(params=>params.id),
map(params=>params.id)
switchMap(id=> this.studentService.getStudentById(id)
).subscribe(student => this.student = student);
```

Comment: Should I replace ngOnInit's code with this code or where can I add it ?

Comment: Yes, yuou should

Comment: The card is still empty.